# Otree: Create random var with a probability distribution that depends on player input

Tags: python, random, probability, distribution, otree

I'm working on my first otree project and I'm pretty overwelmed by everything that goes beyond the easy survey stuff..

I have one input page where the player has to decide on how much points he would like to invest. The amount of points he invests is supposed to influence the probability to get a payoff. My input variable:

```
points = models.IntegerField(
                        label="How many points would you like to invest?",
                        choices=[
                             [0, "None"],
                             [1, "1 point"],
                             [2, "2 points"],
                             [3, "3 points"]])
```

**What I need now is a payoff page where a random generator decides if the player has won or not. Probability distribution is supposed to be as follows:**

- If the player invested 0, he has a chance of (1+0)/10 to win
- If the player invested 1, he has a chance of (1+1)/10 to win
- If the player invested 2, he has a chance of (1+2)/10 to win
- If the player invested 3, he has a chance of (1+3)/10 to win

**On this payoff page it is supposed to say "You have rolled the number [x]. That means you have [won, lost]."**

The only thing I could find online was this python-related information: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sample-a-random-number-from-a-probability-distribution-in-python but I didn't get it to work with otree..

**What code do I have to put where to get this to work?**

Comment: if you do `random.randint(1,10)` and the number is less than or equal to "investment+1", then they won.  Isn't that enough?

Comment: This is genious! Thank you so much, this is totally working for me! How can I upvote this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code fragment to generate results using Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

for invested in range(0, 4):
    # Use the provided formula to calculate win probability
    win_prob = (1 + invested) / 10
    # Loss probability = 1 - Win Probability
    loss_prob = 1 - win_prob
    # Get a random result
    result = np.random.choice(['Win', 'Loss'], p=[win_prob, loss_prob])
    # Show the result
    print(f'Win Probability: {win_prob}, Result: {result}')
```

Comment: This looks really good, however I wasn't able to use it because when starting the devserver I get: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'" even though I successfully installed it with pip3. The googled solutions suggested something like my numpy has been installed to the wrong python folder or so!? I didn't really get it.. :/

Comment: What "devserver"?  How are you running this?